# In pyodbc update one column as a python function of another

Tags: pyodbc

In a SQLServer table I want to update the values in colB to transformColumn(colA) where transformColumn is a python function that I don't want to translate to SQL.
I tried the code below but evidently I can't query and update at the same time in this fashion:

```
Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Connection is busy with results for another hstmt (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

How can I achieve my aim?

```
import pyodbc

def transformColumn(colValue):
    #complicated transformation that I don't want to do in SQL here   

cs = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=mySvr;Database=myDB;Trusted_Connection=Yes;'
cn = pyodbc.connect(cs, autocommit=True)

sqlSelect = """
    SELECT id, colA
    FROM myTable    
"""

sqlUpdate = """
    UPDATE myTable 
    SET colB=? WHERE id=?
"""

csrSelect = cn.cursor()
rows = csrSelect.execute(sqlSelect)
csrUpdate = cn.cursor()

row = csrSelect.fetchone()
while row is not None:
    colB = transformColumn(row.colA)
    csrUpdate.execute(sqlUpdate, colB, row.id)    
    row = csrSelect.fetchone()

csrSelect.close()
csrUpdate.close()
cn.close()
```

Comment: I've just realised I can makes this work by running the updates on a different connection but I'd like to know if there's a better or even fundamentally different approach.

Answer (score 2):

The following approach might be a viable alternative if there is an index on [colA]:

```python
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
crsr.execute("SELECT DISTINCT colA FROM myTable")
aList = [item[0] for item in crsr.fetchall()]
for aValue in aList:
    crsr.execute("UPDATE myTable SET colB=? WHERE colA=?", (transformColumn(aValue), aValue))
crsr.close()
cnxn.commit()
```

It would be particularly helpful if there were repeated values in [colA] since the transform is only calculated and applied once for each unique [colA] value

Answer (score 1):

Will the data in `myTable` always be small enough to fit in memory on the machine where this code executes (e.g. always a small lookup table, or will it continue to grow over time)?

**Yes**

Read the `myTable` rows into a list using [Cursor.fetchall()](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#fetchall) which frees up the cursor for use with `UPDATE`

```
# starting line 19 in the code sample
csr = cn.cursor()
# this creates a list of pyodbc.Row objects,
# freeing the cursor for update statement execution
rows = csr.execute(sqlSelect).fetchall()
for row in rows:
    colB = transformColumn(row.colA)
    csr.execute(sqlUpdate, colB, row.id)    
cn.commit()
```

**No**

As you mentioned, use separate connections for the select and update statements. This will perform much better than the above with large sets of data. It does require management of two connection and cursor objects, since updates will be executed while iterating through the select cursor.

```
# starting at line 7 in the code sample
cnSelect = pyodbc.connect(cs, autocommit=True)
cnUpdate = pyodbc.connect(cs, autocommit=True)

sqlSelect = """
    SELECT id, colA
    FROM myTable    
"""

sqlUpdate = """
    UPDATE myTable 
    SET colB=? WHERE id=?
"""

csrSelect = cnSelect.cursor()
csrUpdate = cnUpdate.cursor()
rows = csrSelect.execute(sqlSelect)
for row in rows:
    colB = transformColumn(row.colA)
    csrUpdate.execute(sqlUpdate, colB, row.id)    
cnUpdate.commit()
```

Answer (score -1):

The simple solution to this is use cursor,

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("YOUR SERVER DETAILS, CREDENTIALS")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

query1 = "SELECT * FROM myTable1"
cursor.execute(query1)

query2 = "SELECT * FROM myTable2"
cursor.execute(query2)
```

This way you dont need multiple connections in the same program,